# What are the automorphisms of a Grassmannian?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, grassmannians

I want to know what are the holomorphic automorphisms of a Grassmannian.  Can someone tell me this?

Comment: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1989-106-01/S0002-9939-1989-0938909-8/

Comment: @Carlo: I suggest that you promote your comment to an answer.

Comment: It probably would have been a good idea to quote the paper by Wei-Liang Chow, *On the geometry of algebraic homogeneous spaces*, Ann. of Math. **50** (1949), 32–67, since that is where the original argument is made.

Answer (score 13):

[Automorphisms of Grassmannians](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1989-106-01/S0002-9939-1989-0938909-8/), Michael J. Cowen (1989).

[image]

Comment: What is the dual map?

Comment: @Mostafa -- see section 2 of Cowen's paper for the construction of the dual map.

Comment: Demazure also gave a complete characterization of automorphism groups of generalized Grassmannians $G/P$, "Automorphismes et deformations des varietes de Borel", *Invent. Math.* 1977.  Essentially, the automorphism group of $G/P$ is generated by $G$ (adjoint form) together with certain automorphisms of the Dynkin diagram.  The above is a special case, since $Gr(k,n) = PGL_n/P$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: However, when $n=2p=2$, our Grassmannian ${\rm Gr}(1,{\Bbb C}^2)$ is the projective line ${\Bbb P}^1$, and its automorphism group is ${\rm PGL}(2,{\Bbb C})$ without additional automorphisms, contrary to what Cowen writes.